# What is the logic behind using add = true : and add false : in the problem?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

### SUMMER OF '69: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14
```

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
    for num in arr:
        while add:
            if num != 6:
                total += num
                break
            else:
                add = False
        while not add:
            if num != 9:
                break
            else:
                add = True
                break
    return total
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki please answer if you know. Why we use add = true and while loop ?  I do not get the logic behind using it, can the code to the problem  be done without using nested loop ?

Comment: @user22179543 It's your code, you tell us.

Comment: The `while` loops are indeed unnecessary, because they never last for more than one iteration.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I am at the very learning stage , I managed to find the code but do not understand it completely. Please if you can help me to write the code in easy way that would be a great favour.

Comment: Surprisingly, your code adds, when add==True, and does not add, when add==False. @slothorp is right: you can replace `while` with `if` clauses, if you like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic logic: Numbers are added to `total` if `add` is `True`. We start with `True` and if we reach a `6` we set `add = False`. We set `add` back to `True` if we reach a `9`.

You do not need the `while` loops in your code. With your current logic, each loop is exited after the first run. So the first step will be to replace all these `while` loops with an `if` statement. This also means that the `break` statements are no longer needed.

Rearranging the code will lead to the following result.

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
    for num in arr:
        if add:
            if num == 6:
                add = False
            else:
                total += num
        else:
            if num == 9:
                add = True
    return total
```

---

A different approach that focuses more on testing for the numbers "6" and "9".

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
    for num in arr:
        if num == 6:
            add = False
        elif num == 9 and not add:
            add = True
        else:
            if add:
                total += num
    return total
```

Caveat: One point is unclear in the question - at least for me. How should the algorithm deal with an input like `[6, 9, 9]`? Is the `9` just an indicator to switch to adding again or should the second `9` be added to the result since adding is already activated? In my solutions I assumed the second interpretation.

Comment: If it was a homework assignment, the original code could have been presented. I assume that the questioner really wants to understand the logic, otherwise I would not have answered.

Comment: Thank you so much I was looking for the code which does not use nested loops ......this one clearly makes me understand the logic @Matthias

Comment: @user22179543 If this answer did help you might consider to accept and upvote it. This would compensate the downvote I got for helping you.

Comment: I accepted the answer. However, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote it but why someone downvotes you for helping me? Is this because the question itself is very fundamental in nature or there are any other reasons?

Comment: Maybe someone thought you found code for a homework question somewhere on the web and now ask us to rewrite it so it's presentable. Answering such a question could indeed be a reason for a downvote.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need *while* loops. You just need to know when you're skipping values - i.e., those between 6 and 9 inclusive

```
def summer_69(lst):
    total = 0
    skip = False
    for v in lst:
        if skip:
            if v == 9:
                skip = False
        elif v == 6:
            skip = True
        else:
            total += v
    return total

print(summer_69([1, 3, 5]))
print(summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
print(summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]))
```

**Output:**

```
9
9
14
```